# How do I delete executable JAR after running it inside Java program?

Tags: java, executable-jar, delete-file

I am using a Java program to download JARs from a private online database, and then run them using the following code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
File jarFile = new File(JAR_DIR);
pb.directory(jarFile);
Process proc = pb.start();
```

The JARs run fine using this, but I would like to delete each JAR after using it because there are a ton of them and it would require too much space to just continue downloading them.

I have been printing out each line in the JAR and then waiting for it to close (I have also tried destroying the process after waiting for it to close):

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
String line;
while(line = r.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println(line);
proc.waitFor();
```

Then I delete the folder where the JAR is located using a method from **org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils**:

```
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(jarDirectory));
```

However, this throws an Exception saying the JAR file can't be deleted.

I think there's somewhere I need to remove the JAR's path from the JVM before deleting it, but I haven't found anything on how to do this inside another Java Program.

Comment: Are the java applications still running when you try to delete the `jar` file?

Comment: never done anything like this. but maybe you need to close the reader instances (r.close()...) before deleting

Comment: You could use File.deleteOnExit() to delete the temporary jar files when your program exits. Although this have problems if the JVM crashes, it is the best option after a File.delete() (which didn't work for you, no idea why).

Comment: It depends on the JVM if you can delete currently running .jar files. Oracle JVM under Windows does not allow it, and so you have to wait until the processes (accessing JVMs) end. Under Linux I experienced that most JVM would allow deletion of running or library-bound .jar files.

Comment: @JayC667 That’s because *Linux* (or rather, the POSIX filesystem layer) allows deleting files while they’re opened, something that Windows doesn’t. The JVM merely forwards to the underlying behaviour.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I know the FS behaviours. But I would not bet on it that all JVMs behave the same. Some might load an release the file before running it, some might keep the locks longer because the JVM hasn't shut down yet, due to possible debuggers and what not, and some might have additional locking mechanisms. I haven't read JVM specifications, maybe I am wrong and it dictates the lock/release of JVM implementations and all JVMs stick to that.